# split pngs for sidescroller

Tags: image

I want to split a long png from my artist into vertical chunks that I can load into my code for a side scroller.

Is there a tool that will help do that or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Couldn't you just keep it as one texture and render parts?

Comment: although not specifically what I was asking, this is the correct answer.  The library I am using supports 'atlas' images.  Make your comment an answer and  will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a texture atlas, or a tilesheet of some kind. One texture in video memory is much less work than 100 textures in video memory.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.imagemagick.org/ which you can control from the command line to process images.

Comment: imagemagick does the job, but the comment above is 'more correct' in that I should be using an atlas and taking textures from there.  thanks.